# Perl5 DBI Mysql: reliable way to get last_insert_id

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dancer

In my code I use `database->last_insert_id(undef,undef,undef,"id");` to get the autoincremented primary key. This works 99.99% of the time. But once in a while it returns a value of 0. 
In such situations, Running a select with a WHERE clause similar to the value of the INSERT statement shows that the insert was successful. Indicating that the last_insert_id method failed to get the proper data.

Is this a known problem with a known fix? or should I be following up each call to last_insert_id with a check to see if it is zero and if yes a select statement to retrieve the correct ID value?

My version of mysql is
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64)

Edit1: Adding the actual failing code.

```
use Dancer2::Plugin::Database;
<Rest of the code to create the insert parameter>
eval{
     database->quick_insert("build",$job);
     $job->{idbuild}=database->last_insert_id(undef,undef,undef,"idbuild");
     if ($job->{idbuild}==0){
        my $build=database->quick_select("build",$job);
        $job->{idbuild}=$build->{idbuild};
        }
     };
debug ("=================Scheduler build Insert=======================*** ERROR :Got Error",$@) if $@;
```

Note: I am using Dancer's Database plugin. Whose description says,

> Provides an easy way to obtain a connected DBI database handle by
>   simply calling the database keyword within your Dancer2 application
>
> Returns a Dancer::Plugin::Database::Core::Handle object, which is a
>   subclass of DBI's DBI::db connection handle object, so it does
>   everything you'd expect to do with DBI, but also adds a few
>   convenience methods. See the documentation for
>   Dancer::Plugin::Database::Core::Handle for full details of those.

Comment: You know that that returns the last insert by that database handle, right?  Are you doing it immediately after the insert, or doing other things first?  Could the connection be timing out (or killed) and your client is getting a new handle?  I'm pretty sure there isn't some widespread problem with last_insert_id, so there's likely something funky with your code.  Show it.

Comment: I have updated my original question to add a failing code fragment.
I am calling last_insert_id immediately after the insert.
I have passed `RaiseError` and `PrintError` options to my connection but I do not see any error messages for this failure.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this type of problem before, but I suspect your closing note may be the key.  Dancer::Plugin::Database transparently manages database handles for you behind the scenes.  This can be awfully convenient... but it also means that you could change from using one dbh to using a different dbh at any time.  From [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Database#GETTING-A-DATABASE-HANDLE):

> Calling `database` will return a connected database handle; the first time it is called, the plugin will establish a connection to the database, and return a reference to the DBI object. On subsequent calls, the same DBI connection object will be returned, **unless it has been found to be no longer usable (the connection has gone away), in which case a fresh connection will be obtained.**

(emphasis mine)

And, as ysth has pointed out in comments on your question, `last_insert_id` is handle-specific, which suggests that, when you get 0, that's likely to be due to the handle changing on you.

But there is hope!  Continuing on in the D::P::DB docs, there is a `database_connection_lost` hook available which is called when the database connection goes away and receives the defunct handle as a parameter, which would allow you to check and record `last_insert_id` within the hook's callback sub.  This could provide a way for you to get the id without the additional query, although you'd first have to work out a means of getting that information from the callback to your main processing code.

The other potential solution, of course, would be to not use D::P::DB and manage your database connections yourself so that you have direct control over when new connections are created.

Comment: Quoting from the doc. 

>Takes care of ensuring that the database handle is still connected and valid. If the handle was last asked for more than connection_check_threshold seconds ago, it will check that the connection is still alive, using either the $dbh->ping method if the DBD driver supports it, or performing a simple no-op query against the database if not. If the connection has gone away, a new connection will be obtained and returned. This avoids any problems for a long-running script where the connection to the database might go away.

Comment: In the code above the insert is immediately followed by last_insert_id()... So the probability of there being a sufficient large gap for the connection to drop is very low...

I will try to write a hook to print out a message whenever connection is lost and see whether it is the source of this problem...

Comment: @vijayvithal - I agree that it seems unlikely, but this is the only potential explanation I (or, it seems, anyone else) can come up with. I look forward to hearing whether your hook experiment confirms or denies my theory.